# Catching Errors to Fix Promise Rejections

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was getting some unhandled promise rejection errors, and am trying to catch them and console them after each `.then` statement

However, I am getting an 'unexpected token' when trying to run on my server with the period at `.try`

I tried different formats and tried removing the `try` in general but to no avail.
Can someone provide some tips on how to avoid a syntax error in this case?

```
 app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
 .init().then(async function()  {
        .try {  
        } catch (error) {
        }(err => console.log(err)) ;
      .open(decodeURIComponent(req.query.url)).then((site)  => {
          site.analyze().then(async function(results) {
            .try {
            } catch (error) {
            }(err => console.log(err));  
            res.json(results);
```

For additional context: This is an express application.

Comment: Your code doesn't parse, and it's not obvious how to correct it. Is there a comma missing before the two `(err => ...)` statements, or a `}`? Also what is that `.` in `.try`?

Comment: The unexpected token is the dot before `try`. Your code isn't well formed. You can use a try/catch block `try {} catch(e) {}` or the `.catch()` method as suggested in answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `.try` is not really attached to anything, because it is in the callback of your `.then()` function. I don't think you need a try at all, you can just do something like

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  wappalyzer.init().then(async function()  {
    // do something on success
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ambiguous, see comment. But my guess is that what you are looking for is the proper way to handle exceptions in the promises you are currently handling the resolve case of (`then`), but not yet the rejections, in which case this might be what you are looking for:

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  wappalyzer.init().then(function() {
    // handle success ... 
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  wappalyzer.open(decodeURIComponent(req.query.url)).then((site)  => {
    site.analyze().then(function(results) { 
      // handle success ... 
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    res.json(results); 
  })
}
```